# MySql Wrong command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in the sql:

```
client
id   first
1    david
2    jenna
3    ben

rating
id  clientid userid rating ratetext         date
1   1        3      4      Very good        12/4/2012
2   3        6      3      Simple bla bla   5/3/2013
```

And i want to get all the rating for a `userid`
so i try something like:

```
SELECT rating,ratetext,date,first FROM rating r 
INNER JOIN client c ON r.userid = 3;
```

But i always get the rows with other rows that i don't need to get. any idea what is wrong with my command?

Comment: I am not clear on what the difference is between a user and a client here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT rating, ratetext, date, first 
FROM   rating r INNER JOIN client c 
ON     r.clientid = c.id
WHERE  r.userid = 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to select ratings with the explicitly specified ID, and the corresponding clients because on the `clientid` stored in the `rating` record:

```
SELECT rating,ratetext,date,first FROM rating r 
INNER JOIN client c ON c.id = r.clientid
WHERE r.userid = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your joins should describe what two pieces of information connects the two tables. You want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM rating r, client c WHERE r.clientid=c.id AND r.userid=3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT r.rating, r.ratetext, r.date, c.first
FROM rating AS r
INNER JOIN client AS c
  ON r.clientid = c.id
WHERE r.userid = 3
```

You should join on the client id columns of the two tables and then use userid in where clause to filter.

Make sure you have indexes on r.clientid and r.userid.